# What is the intended error in the faulty sentence 她着装简洁，言谈高雅，第一次见面，我被她的美所深深吸引了?

Tags: grammar

This is a "faulty sentence" question from the HSK6 Standard Course workbook (chapter 8, page 63; [photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xraoS.jpg); OCR by Yandex):

> 20. A 有人为追求浪漫，在屋子里安装上许多彩灯。
>     B 从广义上讲，预危动物泛指珍贵、稀有的野生动物。
>     C **她着装简洁，言谈高雅，第一次见面，我被她的美所深深吸引了**。
>     D 我是个随性的人，我不喜欢的事就不干，只要喜欢，玩儿了命也要往里钻。

The given answer is C, but I don't know why.  A question was asked on [HiNative](https://hinative.com/questions/16281814):

> This sentence has an error: 她着装简洁，言谈高雅，第一次见面，我被她的美所深深吸引了。 do I change it to this? —> 我深深地被她的美所吸引了。

One answer was merely 对的，非常好, and another was 可以, which didn't give an explanation.  One was 我被她的美深深吸引了 听起来更自然, which deletes the 所 instead, but again, it doesn't explain which grammar rule is being violated.  Another answer said:

> ……我认为问题应该是出现在“被. . 所. . 结构”上。" 为. . 所. ." 这个意思等于" 被" 但是现在汉语使用习惯喜欢杂揉在一起。……

So they're claiming the 被……所 structure is considered incorrect.  [This question](https://www.zhihu.com/question/323334029/answer/679432094) quotes the survey 邵敬敏《现代汉语通论》, giving examples of 被……所:

> [image: Examples of 被……所 being used in 邵敬敏's textbook]

And [this question about 我们被老师动听歌声和笑容所深深吸引](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/356033171.html) at Baidu Zhidao, also has inconsistent answers.

It is not hard to find comparable examples online, such as  为什么我们总是会被渣男所深深吸引？  ([source](https://www.sohu.com/a/479708580_120007785)) or 如何让自己被一本小说所深深吸引？ ([source](https://www.qijizuopin.com/ask/q29163866437967872?source=m_jump)).

**Question**: What is the intended error in the faulty sentence 她着装简洁，言谈高雅，第一次见面，我被她的美所深深吸引了?

Comment: Dressing neatly and speaking elegantly does not mean someone is beautiful

Answer (score 2):

I think you can say:

(1) 第一次见面, 我就**被**她的美深深地吸引**了**. 多年过去, 我依然记得. (without 所)

(2) 第一次见面时, 我**被**她的美**所**深深吸引, 竟然有点语无伦次了. (without 了)

(3) 第一次见面时, 我**被**她的美深深吸引, 竟然有点语无伦次了. (without 了，omitted 所)

(4) 第一次见面, 她的美深深地吸引了我.

Noun-A **被** noun-B **所** verb-do is a passive sentence. It is usually used as a clause. Otherwise, the word **所** is often omitted. It seems that **所** and **了** do not appear in the same sentence. For example,

他**被**虚假广告**所**欺骗，买了这些质量不好的食品。

他**被**虚假广告骗了，买了这些质量不好的食品。

My final notes: I searched websites and grammar books. I did not find the grammar rules that say that you cannot use **所** and **了** together。The above answer is based on my practice.

Comment: https://nufs-nuas.repo.nii.ac.jp/record/126/files/08.pdf 陆俭明认为带了“所”只表示已然的事。已然=已经。My understanding is that “所” already has the meaning of “了”.

Answer (score 2):

> 第一次见面，我**被**她的美**所**深深**吸引**了。

"被/为 + something + 所 + verb" is a patterned expression to convey - "an act (indicated by the verb) is/was caused by something (in the description). In the sentence, 深深(deep/keen) is to be eliminated.

- 第一次见面，我就**被**她的美(something)**所**吸引(verb). - At first sight, I am/was already attracted (to her) by her beauty.

Or, if the emphasis on the intensity of the attraction is necessary/desirable, we can say:

- 第一次见面，我就**深深地**被她的美所吸引. - At first sight, I am/was already deeply attracted (to her) by her beauty.

Another way to write this sentence is by eliminating the word "所":

- 第一次见面，我(就)被她的美(深深地)吸引(着)了.

**Additional Discussion:**

Note that the example sentences in 邵敬敏's work - "我們不能被花言巧語所迷惑" and "他從不為金前所動", both fall in the pattern described above.

**Suggested fixes** - (for the remaining examples in the question)

1. "为什么我们总是会被渣男所深深吸引" - Simply eliminate the word "深深".
2. "如何让自己被一本小说所深深吸引？" For this sentence to make sense, "让" should be changed to "不让" - "如何**不让**自己被一本小说所深深吸引？". Now, the fixes are the same as before:

- 如何不让自己被一本小说所吸引？

Or,

- 如何不让自己深深地被一本小说所吸引？

Answer (score 1):

> 她着装简洁，言谈高雅，第一次见面，我被她的美所深深吸引了。

Dressing neatly and speaking elegantly does not mean someone is beautiful

The two things sound like they are happening independently of each other

It makes more sense: 她着装简洁，言谈高雅，第一次见面，我被她深深吸引了- She dressed and spoke elegantly. I was deeply attracted to her when we first met.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly agree with r13.

I think the problem/mistake in the HSK sentence is simply that you normally can't put anything between 所 and the following verb.

So the solution is either to eliminate 所, which is almost often possible without changing the meaning, or to change the place of the adverb (ie, not between 所 and following 动词).

But I am incapable of finding anything authoritative to confirm this rule.